# Manual installation of gitlab-runner on RHEL fails

Tags: linux, server, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, rhel

My Environment is RHEL, I'm trying to install gitlab-runner on my linux server which does not have internet connectivity. Thus, I cannot curl -:
**curl -L https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-runner/script.rpm.sh | bash**
So, instead I downloaded the linux setup from https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/bleeding-edge.html#download-any-other-tagged-release. And further more I copied that setup to the server from my local system.

Could someone please tell me the next step how to further insatll it??

I'm trying to install the gitlab-runner setup on my linux server which does not have internet access.

Comment: have you tried downloading the RPM https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/bleeding-edge.html#download-one-of-the-packages-for-red-hat-or-centos. And then following https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html